# how do i make this rectangle keep moving till a new key is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

i want the rectangle to move in the direction the user gives until a new key is pressed.

making a loop inside just hangs the program since the loop would just become an infinite loop.
i tried putting that if statement at the `bottom` because i thought the `root.mainloop()` function causes the program to loop but that didn't work either.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x1 = y1 = 250
direc = "none"

score = 0
walls = ["250 250"]

score_box = tk.Label(root, text=score)
score_box.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1+10, y1+10)

def draw_rect():
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1+10, y1+10, fill="green")

def score_add():
    global score, x1, y1
    score += 1
    score_box["text"] = score
    coords = str(x1) + " " + str(y1)
    if coords in walls:
        print(f"you lose! your final score was {score}")
        root.destroy()
    walls.append(coords)


def move(event):
    global x1, y1, direc
    if event.char == "d":
        x1 += 10
        direc = "right"
    draw_rect()
    if event.char == "a":
        x1 -= 10
        direc = "left"
    draw_rect()
    if event.char == "s":
        y1 += 10
        direc = "down"
    draw_rect()
    if event.char == "w":
        y1 -= 10
        direc = "up"
    draw_rect()
    score_add()

# doesn't run at all
if direc == "up":
    y1 -= 10
    print("test")
    draw_rect()
    score_add()

# runs once only at the start
print("hello")

root.bind("<Key>", move)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `after()` to keep the rectangle moving:

```
import tkinter as tk

dx = dy = 0
delay = 100  # in milliseconds, adjust it to set difficulty

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 500
SIZE = 10

score = 0
x1, y1 = WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2
walls = [(x1, y1)]


def draw_rect():
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1+SIZE, y1+SIZE, fill="green")

def score_add():
    global score
    score += 1
    score_box["text"] = score
    coords = (x1, y1)
    if coords in walls or x1 < 0 or x1 >= WIDTH or y1 < 0 or y1 >= HEIGHT:
        print(f"you lose! your final score was {score}")
        root.destroy()
    walls.append(coords)

def move():
    global x1, y1
    if dx or dy:
        x1 += dx
        y1 += dy
        draw_rect()
        score_add()
    root.after(delay, move)

def set_direction(event):
    global dx, dy
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        dx, dy = 0, -SIZE
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        dx, dy = 0, SIZE
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        dx, dy = -SIZE, 0
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        dx, dy = SIZE, 0


root = tk.Tk()

score_box = tk.Label(root, text=score)
score_box.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

root.bind("<Key>", set_direction)

draw_rect() # draw the starting rectangle
move() # start the moving loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i tried running the code you provided as is and it did not function correctly, after the first square was drawn when the program starts it was non responsive. no movement when i press a key.

Comment: @TheolinNadasen It works fine in my Python 3.8.5 in Windows 10.  You can try changing the checking for `keysym` to `char` like your original post.

Comment: changing it to `char` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of using threading to keep that rectangle moving until a different direction key is pressed. I have some code that you can try by replacing the `move` function with following modified portion -

```
from threading import Lock, Thread
from time import sleep

key_press_delay = .5  # Half a second

# Simulates last valid key press to be repeated
def hold_key_press_thread():
    global x1, y1, direc, char, key_press_delay
    loop = True
    while loop:
        if char == "d":
            x1 += 10
            direc = "right"
        elif char == "a":
            x1 -= 10
            direc = "left"
        elif char == "s":
            y1 += 10
            direc = "down"
        elif char == "w":
            y1 -= 10
            direc = "up"
        draw_rect()
        score_add()
        sleep(key_press_delay)

char = ' '
key_lock = Lock()
key_thread = Thread(target=hold_key_press_thread)
key_thread.setDaemon(True)

def move(event):
    global char, key_lock, key_thread
    key_lock.acquire()
    char = event.char
    key_lock.release()

    if not key_thread.is_alive():
        key_thread.start()
```

Please note that it may have issues that I am not aware of or undesirable to what you want. For example, a key press could get lost while the thread is as sleep. I would also love to know of other better ways this could have been done.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have tried your solution and it worked well enough. if no better answer is given then i will accept this one.